# Leitura uma matriz de um arquivo

Tags: c

Estou querendo ler de um arquivo que possui uma matriz dentro, a quantidade de linhas e colunas e printar na tela, mas o meu programa não aparece nada, ele simplesmente para e não printa o número de linhas(counterL) e de colunas(counterC).

O programa está logo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
A funcao abaixo tem como utilidade a alocacao dinamica de uma matriz
*/

int** alocaMatriz(int linha, int coluna)
{
    int i, j;
    int** matriz = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < linha; i++)
    {
        matriz = (int**) malloc(linha * sizeof(int*));
        for(j = 0; j < coluna; j++)
        {
            matriz[i] = (int*) malloc(coluna * sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    return matriz;
}

/*
A funcao abaixo tem como utilidade a liberacao de memoria de uma matriz alocada
dinamicamente
*/

void liberaMatrizes()
{

}

int main (void)
{

    int aux, counterL = 0, counterC = 0;
    int** matrizRetorno = NULL;
    char* nomeArquivo = NULL;
    size_t tamanho = 0;
    FILE * ponteiro;


    getline(&nomeArquivo, &tamanho, stdin);

    nomeArquivo[strlen(nomeArquivo) - 1] = '\0';

    ponteiro = fopen(nomeArquivo, "r");

    while(fscanf(ponteiro, "%d", &aux) != '\n')
    {
        counterC++;
        if(fscanf(ponteiro, "%d", &aux) == '\n')
            counterL++;
    }

    printf("%d\n%d\n", counterL, counterC);

    matrizRetorno = alocaMatriz(counterL, counterC);

    fclose(ponteiro);

    liberaMatrizes();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resultados vericados**

Eu compilei o teu programa (depois das minhas [alterações](http://pastebin.com/upCn4Afk)) e vou-te dizer que não funciona. A função que deves usar é `fgets`. Vê [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861793/trouble-reading-a-line-using-fscanf).

**Solução**

Para lermos um ficheiro utilizando o [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) fazemos um loop, ela retorna NULL quando não há caracteres para serem lidos ou `EOF`. O segundo argumento do `fgets`é a quantidade caracteres a ser lido, normalmente o tamano da string que se passou. O terceiro é o apontador para o ficheiro. A função para de ler a linha quando encontra um `\n`, ou `\0` ou o final do ficheiro `EOF`.

**Então como fazemos as contas?**

A quantidade de linhas vai ser o nº de linhas lido e a de colunas o máximo nº de caracteres lido numa linha. Neste caso escolhi 20, mas você pode mudar.

```
    char lido[20];
   while(fgets(lido, 20, ponteiro))
   {
       if(counterC < (strlen(lido)-1)) //Pois inclui o \n e o \0
   {
       counterC = (strlen(lido)-1);

     }
     counterL++;


    }
```

**Para acrescentar**

A função [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) coloca o caractér terminador automaticamente.

> getline() reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of
>          the buffer containing the text into *lineptr.  The buffer is null-
>          terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

Basicamente coloca o caráter terminador e um `\n`, se este for encontrado.

**Resultado de compilação**

Notar que utilizei um ficheiro que continha o seguinte:

```
ab
cv
ed
```

Este foi o output( teste é o nome do executável depois de compilado ):

```
C:\Users\NAMS\Desktop>teste
3
2
```

Comment: Mas eu não qual o tamanho de linhas e colunas do meu arquivo, a pessoa insere o arquivo txt e o meu programa conta

Comment: Não sei se leu o segundo link que mandei. Basicamente se o scanf falhar poderá deixar o seu apontador num local desconhecido trazendo problemas futuros. No caso do tamnho das linhas e colunas pode sempre criar uma string com um tamanho como 4098 ou 10240, duvido que alguem escreva tanto numa linha e se houver deve ser um troll.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(fscanf(ponteiro, "%d", &aux) != '\n')
    {
        counterC++;
        if(fscanf(ponteiro, "%d", &aux) == '\n')
            counterL++;
    }
```

Este é um ciclo infinito. O valor devolvido pelo primeiro `fscanf()` **NUNCA** vai ser igual a `'\n'`.

Cada membro da familia de funções `scanf` devolve o número de atribuições efectuadas (que pode ser `0`) ou `EOF` em caso de erro. No teu caso, como tens apenas uma atribuição possível o valor devolvido vai ser um dos três `{ EOF, 0, 1 }`

Suponho que o que queres fazer seja ler dois números do principio do ficheiro sem te preocupares com espaços em branco ou quebra de linhas.
Experimenta assim

```
   if (fscanf(ponteiro, "%d%d", &counterC, &counterL) != 2) /* erro */;
```